# Case statement errors

Tags: sql, oracle, case

keep getting error missing keyword after the When on line 3 i know i am doing something wrong in the case statement but cant figure out what

```
select DISTINCT p.code, a.itemno, a.descrip, a.rev, a.class, a.std_cost, a.std_price, t.trans_in_out, t.trans_quan,
    (select case when V.MIN_CUST_PRICE is null then
    when V.MIN_CUST_NAT_PRICE is null then
    when V.MIN_SELL_PRICE is null then 0
    else V.MIN_SELL_PRICE
    else V.MIN_CUST_NAT_PRICE
    else V.MIN_CUST_PRICE
    end
    from v_sca_item_price_summary v where rownum = '1') as Value
    from arinvt a, translog t, eplant e, v_sca_item_price_summary v, prod_code p
    where v.arinvt_id = a.id
    and a.prod_code_id = p.id
    and t.eplant_id = e.id
    and t.trans_date between :start_date and :end_date
```

Comment: select case when V.MIN_CUST_PRICE is null then (then what?)

Comment: i am trying to basically say that if any of the following  V.MIN_CUST_NAT_PRICE V.MIN_SELL_PRICE  V.MIN_SELL_PRICE is null then the one with a value should be the end result

Answer (score 2):

Change whole `case when...` to [**`coalesce()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617):

```
coalesce(V.MIN_CUST_PRICE, V.MIN_CUST_NAT_PRICE, V.MIN_SELL_PRICE, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Oracle nested CASE statements](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_nested_case.htm) It should be like this:

```
select DISTINCT p.code, a.itemno, a.descrip, a.rev, a.class, a.std_cost, a.std_price, t.trans_in_out, t.trans_quan,
    (select case when V.MIN_CUST_PRICE is null then
    (case when V.MIN_CUST_NAT_PRICE is null then
    (case when V.MIN_SELL_PRICE is null then 0
    else V.MIN_SELL_PRICE end)
    else V.MIN_CUST_NAT_PRICE end)
    else V.MIN_CUST_PRICE
    end
    from v_sca_item_price_summary v where rownum = '1') as Value
    from arinvt a, translog t, eplant e, v_sca_item_price_summary v, prod_code p
    where v.arinvt_id = a.id
    and a.prod_code_id = p.id
    and t.eplant_id = e.id
    and t.trans_date between :start_date and :end_date
```

I hope to be helpful for you :)

Comment: hey it worked and run but the only issue its its returning only 0 and not picking up the value for naything to replace the 0

Comment: I gusss value of `V.MIN_CUST_PRICE`, `V.MIN_CUST_NAT_PRICE` and `V.MIN_SELL_PRICE` are null. check it and let me know result.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CASE` syntax is wrong ... actual syntax is

```
CASE WHEN <condition> THEN VALUE
WHEN <condition> THEN VALUE
...
ELSE default_value END
```

Compare that to yours and you will find mistake that you are missing `THEN` value and you have multiple `ELSE` statements

```
case when V.MIN_CUST_PRICE is null then ???
    when V.MIN_CUST_NAT_PRICE is null then ???
    when V.MIN_SELL_PRICE is null then 0
    else V.MIN_SELL_PRICE ???
    else V.MIN_CUST_NAT_PRICE ???
    else V.MIN_CUST_PRICE ???
    end
```